# VK API и формат ссылок

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

*Следующий вопрос*: как отключить форматирование ссылок, которые отправляет бот? Чтобы ссылка казалось простым текстом, а не как обычно делает сайт VK, когда вставляешь ссылку, он добавляет ее название и делает небольшой сниппет.

Пример того, как присылает сообщения бот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример того, как нужно сделать:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Больше подробностей, приведите примеры..

Comment: @Theartofbeingalive сделал. Гляньте..

Comment: а вы посылаете ссылку через API?

Comment: @Theartofbeingalive Да, конечно..это для примера отправил сам себе через сообщения. Но API работает идентично с ссылкой

Comment: можно это обойти, используя конвертацию символов (в данном случае ссылок) в их числовые значения. Пример: [вставьте ссылку в поле, выберите "все символы"](http://forall.ru-board.com/Svarga/cyr_letters_gen.html) и полученные символы отправляйте в API. В качестве реализации на php, могу дать полноценный ответ.

Comment: @Theartofbeingalive Было бы интересно глянуть, если можно

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ в [документации](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send).
В параметрах передать `'dont_parse_links'=> 1` и будет счастье.

Comment: Полезная информация, как-то сразу не увидел, с меня плюсик :)